# Using QTextCursor to select and delete a given row from QTextBrowser

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

I ask for help with the question given in the title.

The textBrowser receives links from the process polling the OTRS server for applications with the 'open' flag, if this flag changes to 'close', then the line intended for deletion is transmitted by another signal and must be deleted from the textBrowser.

Wandering around the Internet and documentation did not help to find the answer.

main.py

```
import os
import sys
import requests
import pygame
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
from pyotrs import Client


class Parser(QThread):
    ticket_list_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    new_ticket_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    ticket_list_remove_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    error_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    cycle_counter = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ticket_tuple = []
        self.links_list = []
        self.removed_link = []
        self.ticket_id_list = []
        self.wait_time = None
        self.url = None
        self.log = None
        self.pas = None
        self.sound_file = None

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.pars()

    def pars(self):
        try:
            response = requests.get(
                f'{self.url}/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/TicketSearch?UserLogin={self.log}&Password={self.pas}',
                )
            response = response.content.decode("utf-8")
            resp_values = eval(response)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f'{ex}')
            self.error_signal.emit('Problems connecting to the server')
        print(resp_values)
        client = Client(self.url, self.log, self.pas)
        client.session_create()

        for item in resp_values['TicketID']:
            ticket = client.ticket_get_by_id(int(item))
            self.ticket_id_list.append(item)

            if ticket.field_get("TicketNumber") not in self.ticket_tuple and ticket.field_get("State") == "open":
                self.ticket_tuple.append(f'{ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")}')

                if self.cycle_counter > 0:
                    self.new_ticket_signal.emit(f'{ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")} {ticket.field_get("Title")}')
                    pygame.mixer.init()
                    pygame.mixer.music.load(self.sound_file)
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                link_url = f'{self.url}/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID={item}'
                self.links_list = f'<a href="{link_url}">№ {ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")} Title: {ticket.field_get("Title")}</a>'
                print(f'BEFORE REMOVE: {self.links_list}')
                self.ticket_list_signal.emit(self.links_list)

            elif ticket.field_get("TicketNumber") in self.ticket_tuple and ticket.field_get("State") != "open":
                self.ticket_tuple.remove(f'{ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")}')
                link_url = f'{self.url}/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID={item}'
                self.removed_link = f'<a href="{link_url}">№ {ticket.field_get("TicketNumber")} Title: {ticket.field_get("Title")}</a>'
                print(f'AFTER REMOVE: {self.removed_link}')
                self.ticket_list_remove_signal.emit(self.removed_link)

            else:
                pass
        print(self.ticket_tuple)
        self.cycle_counter = self.cycle_counter + 1

        if self.cycle_counter > 50:
            self.cycle_counter = 1
        print(self.cycle_counter)
        print(f'TIME WAIT: {self.wait_time}')
        QThread.sleep(self.wait_time)


class ConfGUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConfGUI, self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.sound_file = os.path.join(self.file_path, 'sounds/notice_notice.mp3')
        
        self.ui.lineEdit_4.setText(self.sound_file)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_file)

        self.pars_thread = Parser()
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.create_session)
        self.ticket_links = self.pars_thread.ticket_list_signal.connect(self.links_add, QtCore.Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
        self.new_ticket = self.pars_thread.new_ticket_signal.connect(self.mb, QtCore.Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
        self.remove_ticket_links = self.pars_thread.ticket_list_remove_signal.connect(self.remove_links, QtCore.Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
        self.error_message = self.pars_thread.error_signal.connect(self.mb, QtCore.Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)

    def get_file(self):
        try:
            self.sound_file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select the alarm sound')
            self.sound_file = self.ui.lineEdit_4.textChanged(self.sound_file)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(f'Exception in get folder: {e}', exc_info=True)

    def create_session(self):
        wait_time = int(self.ui.lineEdit_5.text())
        url = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        log = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        pas = self.ui.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.pars_thread.wait_time = wait_time
        self.pars_thread.url = url
        self.pars_thread.log = log
        self.pars_thread.pas = pas
        self.pars_thread.sound_file = self.sound_file
        self.pars_thread.start()

    def links_add(self, links):
        self.ui.textBrowser.append(links)

    def remove_links(self, removed_links): # this method should delete rows
        cursor = self.ui.textBrowser.textCursor()
        # cursor.selectedText(removed_links) # TypeError: selectedText(self): too many arguments
        cursor.selection(removed_links) # TypeError: selection(self): too many arguments
        cursor.removeSelectedText()
        cursor.clearSelection()
        self.ui.textBrowser.textCursor(cursor)

    def mb(self, d_msg):
        dlg = QMessageBox(self)
        dlg.setWindowTitle('Attention!')
        dlg.setText(d_msg)
        dlg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Information)
        dlg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        dlg.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = ConfGUI()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

gui.py

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'gui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 550)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 550))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 550))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "New ticket finder"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "URL"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "http://127.0.0.1"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Login"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Password"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "The interval between requests (sec)"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Notification sound"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select a file"))
```